# Skip foreach loop

Tags: php

Here's a little coding problem for you. The code:

```
if ($categories) { 

    foreach ($categories as $tag) { 

        $tag_link = get_category_link($tag->term_id); 

        //new line 
        if (isset($instance['new-line'])) { 
            $html .= "<div>"; 
        } 

        $html .= "<span class="tagsy-box" style="$box_style">"; 
        $html .= "<a href="{$tag_link}" title="{$tag->name} Tag" class="{$tag->slug}"><span class="tagsy-name-$style $theme_name" style="$name_style">"; 
        $html .= "{$tag->name}</span><span class="tagsy-count-$style $theme_count" style="$count_style">{$tag->count}</span></a></span>"; 

        //new line 
        if (isset($instance['new-line'])) { 
            $html .= "</div>"; } } 
        } 
        else { 
            $html .= "No Categories Available"; 
        }

    }

}
```

The problem: I want to exclude certain categories from displaying. Apparently, the way to do this is to skip the foreach loop for those categories I want to exclude. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code that populates $categories

Comment: Also, I'm assuming your code is spread over several lines and not mostly commented out as it is now, so please reformat it. Lines such as `$html .= "<span class="tagsy-box" style="$box_style">";` will throw errors, as you are nesting unescaped double quotes.

Comment: Here's the whole file: http://pastebin.com/rixJp07d
Relevant bit starts at line 197 (I think).

Answer (score 2):

In line 195 you're using `get_categories`, which can be filtered to exclude specific category numbers, either through an array of arguments, or a query string. Since `$options` is already set, you could add to it before you call `get_categories`:

```
if ($show_assigned_categories == 'true' && is_single()) {
        $categories = get_the_category();
} 
else {
    $options['exclude'] = '1,2,3'; // your comma-separated list goes here
    $categories = get_categories($options);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it broke my site. All that would load is a white screen...

Comment: Hmm. What values did you use for `$options['exclude']`?

Comment: I tried '1, 48'

Comment: A white screen means PHP ran into a a fatal error. You can often see the error in the browser by activating [WordPress Debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). Do **not** leave it activated on a production site.

Comment: I don't know if it'll make a difference, but try removing the space between the comma and the 4. None of the examples I see online have one in there.

Comment: Great! What was the final fix?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude categories you can try this code.

```
$categories = get_categories();    
$category_to_exclude = array(1,2,3);

if ($categories) {
    foreach ($categories as $tag) {
        if( !in_array($tag->term_id, $category_to_exclude) ) {
            $tag_link = get_category_link($tag->term_id);
            echo $tag_link;
        }
    }
}
```

The in_array php function will check the current foreach loop **$tag->term_id** is exists in $category_to_exclude variable. If it not exist, the looping will continue. If it exist, statement will be false and skip the category id.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Explained, hope it helps.